# How do I create an AND filter for the same field

Tags: input-formats

I am having a problem with a view filter. I have one field called Category. The field contains a comma separated list of id numbers that represent different categories. I want to create a filter that will filter out all records that contain one id number, but not another. So my filter is Category=5601 AND Cateogry<>5612. Whenever I create this filter, the result ends up as OR instead of AND.

Answer (score 1):

By default, drupal filters with AND. Maybe you clicked the rearrange and/or option by mistake intsead of just adding a new filter. Try removing both and creating again by clicking add.

[image: drupal-and-or-filter]